# csv files classifcation using CNN

Tags: python, image, keras, conv-neural-network

I have some records of ecg data. each record is in csv form with 12 rows and 500 columns. I am planning to classify these files using 2D CNN. Do i need to convert these csv files to image format? I thought of using imagedatagenerator of keras. will it work of csv files?

Answer (score 0):

yes it works

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(    

featurewise_center=True,

featurewise_std_normalization=True,

rotation_range=20,

width_shift_range=0.2,

height_shift_range=0.2,

horizontal_flip=True)

datagen.fit(x_train)
```

## fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:

```
model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),

      steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...I have a folder named 'training_set', within that around 100 csv record files of above format(each record has 12 rows 500 columns) are there...i need to use these files for training the CNN. I have seen that in many examples where they used to keep jpeg images for training CNN..how to feed the csv matrix files as input to CNN?